# Non-responding FPS Counter in Java

Tags: java, frame-rate

This code is supposed to bring up an application with a green screen and an FPS Counter on the console but its not working.

Help?

```js
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7580815534084638412L;

  public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

  private Thread thread;
  private boolean running = false;

  public Game() {
    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!", this);
  }

  public synchronized void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
  }

  public synchronized void stop() {
    try {
      thread.join();
      running = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while (running) {
      long now = System.nanoTime();
      delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
      lastTime = now;
      while (delta >= 1) {
        tick();
        delta--;
      }
      if (running) {
        render();
        frames++;

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
          timer += 1000;
          System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
          frames = 0;
        }
      }
      stop();
    }
  }

  private void tick() {

  }

  private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
      this.createBufferStrategy(3);
      return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Game();
  }
}
```

```js
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Window extends Canvas {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -240840600533728354L;

  public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

I don't seem to have any problems with window.java but I put it in there just in case.

At the end it is also coming up with 2 errors that say
"Duplicate method run() in type Game, Line 34" And "Duplicate method run() in type Game, Line 61".

Please tell me what went wrong here. Have I not printed it or something?

Comment: If you already know there are some Errors/Exceptions thrown, please share the stacktrace.

Comment: You stated that there are two errors, so please provide more information for them (like stacktraces).

Comment: Oh right, well in game.java there is a line of code saying
"    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
"
It is meant to post the screen it brings up as green
And in my game loop it is meant to bring back that the FPS in the console but is not, I'm undecided if I need to use console.print command. Because apparently it is sopposed to work.

Comment: Works for me, I doubt you posted the same code that was giving you errors.

Comment: I'll repost it but i'm pretty sure.

Comment: @JamesKPolk is it coming up with a green screen because it doesn't seem to be doing that for me. :(

Comment: @JamesKPolk I repasted the code it still doesn't work for me. This is what comes up for me.
http://prntscr.com/8nvd1h

Comment: This is literally the third time I have posted this question for it to be answered. Can someone please help me?!!!